# Adding prebuilt APK to Android system.img (stock firmware from manufacturer)

Tags: custom-roms, rom, device-firmware, development

Can someone help add a prebuilt APK to an Android `system.img` for me? I’ve obtained `boot.img`, `system.img`, etc. (the full firmware) from the manufacturer of the device. I’ve been trying for hours to add the .apk files to the `system.img`. (I’ll share it here)

**My steps:​**

1. What I did was extract the image, add my apk to /app, or /priv-app, or vendor/operator/app.
2. Convert the folders/files of the extracted image to an ISO.
3. Convert the ISO back to .img file using WinISO software
4. Added the system.img converted in step 3 back into the main folder where all the original firmware images are.
5. Flashed the new firmware with the modified `system.img` back to the device.

**Problem:​**

The device boots up to the brand logo. However, it just gets stuck at the brand logo. VERY IMPORTANT => If the flash is successful, then the brand logo turns into brand logo animation, but every time I flash with my APK, it just gets stuck at the unanimated boot logo. Thus there are two stages:

Boot logo = if stuck, then flashing/APK adding failed

Boot Animation = everything works (I know this because the stock flash works just fine)

= extra info=​
Android: 4.4.2
Flash tool: MTK SP Flash Tool

XDA Forums attachment link: https://xdaforums.com/attachments/mx2-wvga_tm-wv3-22-20230418-rar.6039930/

(The above link is the firmware I was able to obtain from the company)

Comment: Some backstory to what im doing: https://xdaforums.com/t/timmkoo-so-close-yet-so-far-android-root-twrp-help-needed-hardest-device-to-mod.4643045/

Comment: Android does not use ISO format. ISO is for CD/DVD. You should better mount the system image on a Linux system and then perform the modifications. Don't extract the image or you will destroy necessary information that can never be recovered.

Comment: Hi @Robert I actually solved this the day before you commented but thank you for your help!! By chance do you know what application/android process is responsible for block installations from outside sources? I read in multiple places that settingsProvider.apk  is the one that determines if an app is installed or not. my goal is to remove this, and install directly to my device.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!